# Convert image files to a csv file

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm working on a The Japanese Female Facial Expression (JAFFE) Database. You can find the database on this link http://www.kasrl.org/jaffe.html.
When I download the database I got a list of pictures. I would like to convert these image files into a CSV file but I'm still new in deep learning and I don't know how. Someone proposed that I work with OpenCV. what should I do?

Comment: a csv is a comma separated information in some form of a table, how can you match an image to that?

Comment: CSV files are _text_ files—how to you propose storing binary image data in one? It's possible, but the resulting CSV file would be huge.

Answer (score 0):

i have simple example
i hope this help you.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import csv


def createFileList(myDir, format='.jpg'):
    fileList = []
    print(myDir)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myDir, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith(format):
                fullName = os.path.join(root, name)
                fileList.append(fullName)
    return fileList
# load the original image
myFileList = createFileList('path/to/directory/')
for file in fileList:
    print(file)
    img_file = Image.open(file)

    # get original image parameters...
    width, height = img_file.size
    format = img_file.format
    mode = img_file.mode

     # Make image Greyscale
     img_grey = img_file.convert('L')
     value = np.asarray(img_grey.getdata(), dtype=np.int).reshape((img_grey.size[1], img_grey.size[0]))


     value = value.flatten()
     print(value)
     with open("img_pixels.csv", 'a') as f:
          writer = csv.writer(f)
          writer.writerow(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Install pillow, numpy, pandas

- Convert the image to RGB
- plot RGB along with x,y co-ordinates in a pandas Dataframe
- Save the dataframe as csv

Sample working code as below

```
 from PIL import Image
    from numpy import array, moveaxis, indices, dstack
    from pandas import DataFrame


    image = Image.open("data.tiff")
    pixels = image.convert("RGB")
    rgbArray = array(pixels.getdata()).reshape(image.size + (3,))
    indicesArray = moveaxis(indices(image.size), 0, 2)
    allArray = dstack((indicesArray, rgbArray)).reshape((-1, 5))


    df = DataFrame(allArray, columns=["y", "x", "red","green","blue"])
    print(df.head())
    df.to_csv("data.csv",index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write any code, you can just use [vips](https://github.com/libvips/libvips) on the command-line on macOS, Linux or Windows.

So, in **Terminal** (or **Command Prompt**, if on Windows):

```
vips im_vips2csv TM.AN1.190.tiff result.csv
```

will convert the 256x256 greyscale image `TM.AN1.190.tiff` into a 256 line CSV with 256 entries per line. Simples!

If you want to replace the tab separators by commas, you can do:

```
tr '\t' , < result.csv  > NewFile.csv
```